# a and not a boolean operations the change in binary values makes no sense

Tags: binary, boolean-operations

if a = 01101001
and b = 01010101

then ~a = 10010110

and ~b = 10101010

the result of ~a makes complete sense to me

but the result of ~b does not can any one please explain ~b?

thank you

Comment: It is hard to see what you would be expecting from `~b` given that `~a` gives you the result you expect.  What do you think should be in `~b` instead of `10101010`?  With that information, we may be able to help explain what's wrong with your interpretation.  How are you testing the results?  Which language are you using, on which platform?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you I will give you the information you need. I am not using any language at the moment. Rather I am self Studying from a book known as computer systems a programers prospective. I have the course next semester and Im just trying to get ahead. but based on how ~a is set up I expected ~b to be 01010101 since b is 01010101 and b is 55 the not of 55 is well, 55. just as the not of a which is 96 as a 69. I figure the figures would of just flip flopped like they did in a. So to say it again, I figured b = 55 ~b = 55 your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Interesting.  You expected a, which is `01101001` to become `10010110` when the `~` (bit-wise inversion operator) is applied, but you didn't expect `01010101` to become `10101010` when the `~` operator is applied?  Computers are nothing if not consistent.  The `~` operator in C and related languages (C++, Java, C#, …) flips each bit in the value it is given.  That's what happened with `a` and is what you expected; it is also what happened with `b` but is apparently not what you expected?  There is no value `x` for which `x == ~x`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please disregard. I figured it out lol im so stupid. The ~x of x just changes the values a 0 becomes 1 a 1 becomes 0 and then the value is figured from that. haha thank you guys

Comment: @JonathanLeffler just to explain my thoughts I wasnt looking at the problem as number in binary i.e 01101001 in a I was thinking about its decimal value. so 01101001 = 69 so that must mean ~a = 96. that my problem I was thinking about the problem wrong I would figure decimal and expect a change based on that. Not in binary form of switching the values of 1 and 0. That was the problem. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Not is just a bit flip.

Truth table:

```
A ~A
0  1
1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

In ~a and ~b, all the bits have flipped from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1 as the case may be.

Comment: i get that guys but it seems not the way in b. I'll take another look at it hard. Thank you